# Vue.js 2.x で、コンポーネントをマウントする方法

Tags: vue.js

SPAでない既存のHTMLの中で、一部Vue.jsのコンポーネントで書き換えるために、
Vue.js 1.xでは以下のようにしていました。

```html
<html>
<body>
  <popup></popup>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Popup from './Popup.vue'

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
      Popup
  }
});
```

Vue.js 2.xで同様のコードを書くと、`Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body>`という警告が出ます。
どう実現したら良いでしょうか？
以下のようにしてみると、コンポーネントのslotが設定されないないようでした。

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Popup from './Popup.vue'

new Vue({
  el: 'popup',
  render: h => h(Popup)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js 2.0からはbodyへのマウントはできなくなりました。

bodyにマウントしてたところをdivタグで囲めば解決できます。

```js
const Popup = {
 template: `<p>popup</p>`
}

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  components: {
      Popup
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <popup></popup>
</div>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。これだけのためにdivタグを記述するのも微妙かなとちょっと思います。